# Simply periodic sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, periodic-functions

I have a definition written by a professor for a simply periodic function.  However, it's written so badly that I cannot understand what he means by it.  To give his definition verbatim he writes the following.  (He uses the reverse "in" symbol, $\ni$, to mean "such that".  Hence $n_0\in N \ni \forall n\geq n_0...$ is read "$n_0$ is a natural number such that, for all $n\geq n_0$, ...)

> Let $\{f_n:n\in N\}$ denote an integer-valued sequence.  We say it is *simply periodic* if: $\exists k\in Z^+$ and $n_0\in N \ni \forall n \geq n_0$:
>
> $$f_n\equiv f_{n+k} \mod{m}$$
>
> and
>
> $$f_{n+1}\equiv f_{n+k+1} \mod{m}$$
>
> then:
>
> $$f_0\equiv f_k \mod{m}$$
>
> and
>
> $$f_1\equiv f_{k+1} \mod{m}$$

Is this saying that, basically, if a sequence is simply periodic then whenever it's periodic "in the forward direction" then it's also periodic all the way back to the first terms?  If my understanding is wrong, can anyone else give me a more readable definition of simply periodic?  I tried searching for one and couldn't find any.

Comment: This a strange definition. First, if $f_n \equiv f_{n+k}$ then $f_{n+1}\equiv f_{n+k+1}$,  since $n\ge n_0$ implies $n+1\ge n_0$. Second, knowing $f_0\equiv f_k$ and $f_1\equiv f_{k+1}$ tells us nothing about $f_2, f_3,\dots,f_{n_0-1}$.

Comment: @Somos tell me about it.  :/

Comment: As usual, the crux is the question: what is the definition supposed to be used for? Definitions are made on purpose. If we know the purpose, we can check if it is useful for  that purpose. There may well be some missing context in which the definition makes sense.